# how to make a hole through only overlay Rectangle using fabric js?

Tags: fabricjs, crop, globalcompositeoperation

I am working on image cropper using fabric js version 1.7.22.
As usually, every cropper display black transparent overlay over the image (where image look like dull), and also display one Rect. (crop Area where image look full with color).

we can create this functionality using fabric js with background image and `fabric.Rect` object.

My problem is that when I use `GlobalCompositeOperation` with `destination-out` property to `fabric.Rect` object. It will make hole through canvas.

In simple word :

when I add `globalCompositeOperation` to `destination-out`, it will make hole through canvas also.

Expected result of canvas: 
[image]

Current Result of canvas:
[image]

I have made one codepen for demonstration : 
https://codepen.io/mayurkukadiya0/pen/zYYWOGL?editors=0110

I have found one codepen also for do same but they are add multiple canvas for display image in separate layer and rect and overlay in separate layer
Is there any way to do this without add external any canvas or css image behind canvas ? 
Here is that reference : https://codepen.io/s0nnyv123/pen/eravaN

Answer (score 3):

try using [setOverlayImage](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Canvas.html#setOverlayImage)

here'a [demonstration](https://codepen.io/EthanYu/pen/wvovQZE?editors=0110), based on your codepen

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas', {preserveObjectStacking: 'true'});
canvas.setHeight(300);
canvas.setWidth(300);

canvas.setOverlayImage('https://images.pexels.com/videos/856973/free-video-856973.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500', canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas), {
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: 300,
    height:300,
    lockMovementX: true,
    lockMovementY: true,
    lockRotation: true,
    selectable: false,
   globalCompositeOperation: 'destination-atop',
});

var overlay = new fabric.Rect({
    left: 0,
    top: 0,
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    fill: '#00000050',
    selectable: false,
    globalCompositeOperation: 'source-over'
});
canvas.add(overlay);

var rect = new fabric.Rect({
     left: 100,
     top: 100,
     width: 100,
     height: 100,
     fill: '#451245',
     globalCompositeOperation: 'destination-out'
});
canvas.add(rect);
canvas.renderAll();
```